# Reading words into an array of strings?

Tags: c

Currently I'm reading each character from the user and storing it into a char array called str. From there I'm trying to use a pointer to loop through the string until it sees a space, once a space is seen I want to take the characters already and create an array of strings. Is that possible? Reasons why I'm doing this is because I later want to use an execlp function to execute a process after my initial program was executed.
[image]

Comment: did you take a look at `strtok`?

Comment: I agree with @Osiris, it the words are delimited, then strtok should suffice

Comment: @Osiris No I haven't I'll take a look. Would I be able to pass the tokens as arguments to the execlp function? if you know anything about that?

Comment: Yes it should work. You can create an array of `char` pointers and pass them to the function.

Comment: @pennyBoy In the future, please copy and paste your code directly into your question, as opposed to including an image of the code. StackOverflow will automatically format any code indented with at least four spaces as code.

Comment: @ricky3350 Ok will do.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to split the string into tokens separated by delimiters you could use the `strtok` function.

An example would be:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int main(void)
{
    int i, n;
    char str[] = "Hello World";
    char *token[4], *act_token;

    token[0] = strtok(str, " ");
    n=1;
    while(n<4 && (act_token=strtok(NULL, " ")))
    {
        token[n] = act_token;
        n++;
    }

    for(i=0;i<n;i++)
    {
        printf("%d: %s\n", i, token[i]);
    }

    return 0;
}
```